# How to specify maven settings.xml for a docker container

Tags: docker, maven

I use maven to build my project.  I am now creating a docker container for this project, and I want the project to be built by the container (multi-step).  However, I have a custom settings.xml file that I need to copy over to the container.  I first copied the settings.xml to my project folder, then:

```
COPY settings.xml /usr/share/maven/ref/
```

I then run the maven command like so:

```
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.m2  mvn --settings /usr/share/maven/ref/settings.xml clean package -Dmaven.test.skip
```

This works.  However, I don't want to copy the `settings.xml` file from `~/.m2/` folder into my working directory.  The `COPY` command does not allow copies from the absolute path of `~/.m2/settings.xml`. (I'm guessing docker considers this a security issue?)

Is there a better option?  I want to use the file that is already there in my .m2 folder.  Any help appreciated.